# ATmega32u4 bootloader

Tags: avr, bootloader

Hey all this would be my first encounter needing to burn the Arduino IDE bootloader onto a blank ATMega32u4 that I bought from Digikey.

What all do I need to buy in order to program the bootloader for that chip? In the manual for the 32u4 it says it comes with a bootloader but I'm guessing its not the arduino bootloader?

Is the pinout for the ISP all that I would need in order to upload the Arduino bootloader?

I've seen this post:

[image]

but I wont be using the through-hole design.. its going to be the surface mount SMD kind so i wouldn't be able to put that on a breadboard.

So would it be as simple as breaking out the ISP pins on the 32u4 and just hooking those up to a Arduino Duemilanove board even if its not the same ATmega chip (As in copying the atmega32u4 arduino to the Duemilanove and then transferring that to the 32u4?)?

Comment: Are you planning to connect to it via USB?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yes i am

Answer (score 2):

The ATmega32U4 already comes programmed with a bootloader that allows programming via USB; once you've added the basic hardware for a USB connection you should be able to use AVRDUDE, FLIP, etc. to upload firmware to the device.

Having said that, putting an ISP connection as per [AVR042](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2521-avr-hardware-design-considerations_applicationnote_avr042.pdf) is highly recommended regardless.

Comment: I know I'm late here, but I'm very interested as to how exactly I would add this "basic hardware"?